# How to forecast the future value using LSTM after predict the test dataset?

Tags: testing, lstm, future, predict, forecast

I use the code bellow to forecast the future value of my dataset after the lstm model was used to predict the test data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the time points for the future forecast
time_points = ['June 2023', 'July 2023', 'August 2023', 'September 2023', 'October 2023', 'November 2023', 'December 2023', 'January 2024', 'February 2024', 'March 2024', 'April 2024', 'May 2024', 'June 2024', 'July 2024', 'August 2024', 'September 2024', 'October 2024', 'November 2024', 'December 2024']

# Get the last observation from the test data as the starting point for future forecasting
last_observation = testX[-1]

# Forecast future data points
future_forecast = []
for _ in range(19):  # Forecasting 19 future months
    # Reshape the last observation to match the model's input shape
    last_observation = np.reshape(last_observation, (1, 1, look_back))

    # Make the next prediction
    next_prediction = best_model.predict(last_observation)

    # Append the prediction to the forecasted data
    future_forecast.append(next_prediction)

    # Update the last observation with the predicted value for the next iteration
    last_observation = np.append(last_observation[:, :, 1:], next_prediction)

# Convert the forecasted data to a numpy array
future_forecast = np.array(future_forecast)

# Reshape the forecasted data to match the original data shape
future_forecast = np.reshape(future_forecast, (-1, 1))

# Inverse transform the forecasted data to get the actual values
future_forecast = scaler.inverse_transform(future_forecast)

# Create a plot for the forecasted values
plt.plot(time_points, future_forecast, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Waktu')
plt.ylabel('Harga CPO')
plt.title('LSTM Forecast')

# Add individual data points on the line
for i, val in enumerate(future_forecast):
    plt.text(time_points[i], val, str(val), horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom')

plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I forecast 20 data for the future but i got the downward trend like bellow

What is wrong with my code? How can i forecast correctly?
Thanks

I try to forecast the furute value of my data using lstm model after the test data being predicted. I hope i can get the better code where there isn't full of trend.